# New Line Character in Linux Prompt?

Tags: linux, perl, newline

I am using qx in Perl to execute commands in a Linux machine.

I'm trying to parse some output in Perl but don't know how to replace the new-line character in multi-line output.

I have been trying something like this:

```
$result =~ s/\\n/||/g;
```

I seem to recall a '\r' with some OSs and I have been trying different combinations with '\n'.

Also, I am starting to have a bunch of lines that look like this, and would like to combime them:

```
$result =~ s/ bytes from /|/g;
$result =~ s/ \(/|/g;
```

Comment: in Linux, it's '\n', in Windows, it's '\r\n'

Comment: Thanks wong2, your comment helped.  I had it almost right, but I did not need a second backslash.

Comment: @wong2, No, on Windows it's `\n` too because the CR LF is converted to LF on read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `\` is either the start of special sequence (if it's followed by a letter), or it causes the next character to be matched literally (if it's followed by a non-letter). Therefore,

```
s/\\n/
```

matches `\` followed by `n`. `\n` is a special sequence that matches a newline, so you want

```
/\n/
```

So you could use

```
my $result = qx{ ... };
$result =~ s/\n/||/g;
```

[perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

---

Regarding the rest,

```
$result =~ s/ bytes from /|/g;
$result =~ s/ \(/|/g;
```

is simply

```
$result =~ s/ bytes from | \(/|/g;
```

Comment: @John R, Ack, silly me, the extra slash was still there in my solution. Added answer to your second question.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using double backslashes, for one thing.

Here is how you can do it:

```
$text = <<EOS;
div class equals main
span id equals marquee
blog! slash span slah div
EOS

print "Before: $text \n\n\n\n";

$text =~ s/\n/\|\|/g;

print "After: $text \n\n\n\n";
```

Here is a codepad for it: http://codepad.org/k0oA2YX4